# Installing CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04 (unmet dependencies)

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and am trying to install CUDA on it. I just couldn't do it.

I install Nvidia R390 driver (which is quite a hassel).

Then I followed the instruction at:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

when  I hit sudo apt-get install cuda

following errors pop up:

```
     Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     cuda-cublas-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-cublas-9-1 (>= 9.1.85.3) but it is not installed
     cuda-cufft-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-cufft-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-curand-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-curand-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-cusolver-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-cusolver-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-cusparse-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-cusparse-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-libraries-9-1 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-nvgraph-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-cusolver-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-cublas-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-cufft-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-curand-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-cusparse-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
                          Depends: cuda-npp-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-npp-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-npp-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-nvgraph-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-1 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-toolkit-9-1 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-9-1 (>= 9.1.85) but it is not installed
     cuda-visual-tools-9-1 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-9-1 but it is not installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I use sudo apt-get -f install, but following errors occurred:

```
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvrtc-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvrtc-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvrtc-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cusolver-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cusolver-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusolver-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cublas-9-1 (9.1.85.3-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cufft-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cufft-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cufft-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../cuda-curand-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-curand-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-curand-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../cuda-cusparse-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-cusparse-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusparse-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../cuda-npp-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-npp-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-npp-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvml-dev-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvml-dev-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvml-dev-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to unpack .../cuda-nvgraph-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvgraph-9-1 (9.1.85-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvgraph-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64', which is also in package cuda-cudart-9-1 9.1.85-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvrtc-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusolver-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cublas-9-1_9.1.85.3-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cufft-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-curand-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-cusparse-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-npp-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvml-dev-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cuda-nvgraph-9-1_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help? I am running out of ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I purged both cuda and nvidia drivers. Then complied tensorflow from source for cuda 9.1 per this instruction and it finally works: http://www.python36.com/install-tensorflow141-gpu/

Answer (score 2):

- download the latest version from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604)
- then stop you X display manager  (lightdm is default for ubuntu)

  ```
  sudo service lightdm stop
  ```
- INSTALL DISPLAY DRIVER (recommended) AND CUDA TOOLKIT

  ```
  sudo chmod +x  cuda_9.0_linux.run
  sudo ./cuda_9.0_linux.run
  ```
- POST-INSTALL ( add these lines to the end of your  `.bashrc` file )

  ```
  export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-9.0
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

  PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
  export PATH
  ```
- CUDNN INSTALL(optional)

  get the CUDNN stuff from [HERE](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuDNN)

  ```
  tar -xzvf cudnn-X.Y.tgz
  cd cudnn-X.Y/cuda
  sudo cp -r * /usr/local/cuda-9.0
  sudo ldconfig
  ```

  just remember to check which versions of cuda and cudnn are supporterd by the tensorflow version you  are going to install. (  for example cuda9.0, cudnn7 for tensorflow 1.7 which is the latest version when i write this answer)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I was trying to install CUDA 9-1 not 9.0. It was during the installation process where I had trouble. I understand that currently tensorflow does not support cuda 9.1 from deb. But my plan was to build from source since tensorflow will inevitably support 9.1 in the future. On a different note, I noticed that Nvidia R390 was trying to wipe out CUDA 9.1 when installed while CUDA 9.1 was trying to revert R390 back to R387. Have you experienced that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't replicated the problem but your trace suggests that the /boot partition is running out of space. Try clearing some old kernels, then re-run the command. Your installation should resume normally. I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had trouble executing sudo apt-get autoremove as it complains about unmet dependencies. I removed one of the PPAs and it seems to temporarily fixed the issue.However, other problems come up. I think I made a big mistake by not removing CUDA 9.0 properly while installing 9.1. For now, I may have to wipe the entire Ubuntu and reinstall it as so many system config got messed up.